# Detokenization returns 'type error' float found expected string

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I have a range of tokenized, training data for my model which initially looked like this :

```
 sucks how one over can ruin everything  
 thank you my love!!!!
```

But after a bit of pre-processing, I have ended up to this.

```
   [['sucks', 'how', 'one', 'over', 'can', 'ruin', 'everything', -0.208],
    ['thank', 'you', 'my', 'love', '!', '!', '!', 0.791]]
```

Code to tokenize :

```
temp = []
for tweet in tweets :
    temp.append(tokenizer.tokenize(tweet))
```

The emojis have been replaced by their sentiment score, but are causing me a problem to detokenize.
I have tried all of the other similar answers but every one of them gives :

**TypeError: sequence item 23: expected str instance, float found**

Can anyone please suggest something?
(The data has been tokenized using Tweet Tokenizer)

Comment: Can you show the code you use to tokenize?

Comment: Yes so I have my 'tweets' (pandas.Series), and then I do temp = [] for tweet in tweets :
    temp.append(tokenizer.tokenize(tweet))

Comment: What is the tokenization goal? To split into words, punctuation/symblols and emoji?

Comment: Yes in order to remove punctuations are replace each emoji with its sentiment score

Comment: If two different emojis have the same sentiment score, how do you plan to detokenize?

Comment: why would their sentiment score matter when detokenizing?